# $\eta$ is a random variable with $\Bbb{E}[\eta]=0$. Does $\Bbb{E}[e^{\eta}]=e^{\Bbb{E[\eta]}}$?

Tags: probability

$\eta$ is a random variable with $\Bbb{E}[\eta]=0$. Does $\Bbb{E}[e^{\eta}]=e^{\Bbb{E[\eta]}}=1$? Why?

Comment: Please don't change the question. If you want, you can ask a new one or maybe add to your existing question.

Comment: And $\mathbb E[\mathrm e^\eta]\gt1$ (strict inequality) except when $\eta=0$ almost surely.

Answer (score 3):

It does not. Take $\eta=-1$ or $\eta=1$ with equal probability. Then
$$
\mathbb{E}(e^\eta)=e^{-1}\frac{1}{2}+e\frac{1}{2}\neq 1
$$

There is no "shortcut" to compute $\mathbb{E}(e^{\eta}) $, other than either finding the distribution of $e^\eta$ or using the formula
$$
\sum_{k} e^kp(k)
$$

or in the continuous case
$$
\int_{Dom(\eta)} e^xf(x)dx
$$

Comment: So what's the solution to $\mathbb{E}(e^\eta)$?

Comment: You mean in general or in this particular example?

Comment: I mean in general